# What is the easiest way to install Meld on RedHat Linux RHEL 5.4?

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm

My company has RedHat RHEL 5.4 on the Linux box, and I need to install Meld on it.  How can it be done?

```
$  sudo yum install meld
No package meld available.
Nothing to do

$  sudo yum search meld
No Matches found
```

The website http://meldmerge.org/ has the download but there is no instructions on how to install it, and the website http://pkgs.repoforge.org/meld/ has `meld-1.1.5-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm`  and `meld-1.1.5-1.rf.src.rpm`  Are they the ones to be used for RHEL 5.4 (not the `src` one?) and how to install it -- is it by using `rpm`?  Can you give the exact lines on the command lines.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the file you want to install.

Then: yum install "whatever_the_filename_is"

If the package is not signed: yum –nogpgcheck install "whatever_the_filename_is"

Comment: so in this case, you mean first download `meld-1.1.5-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm` and then `yum install meld-1.1.5-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm`

Comment: Just be careful, packages that haven't been vetted by your distribution carry the risk of getting maintenance refused for installing non-suported stuff. _You_ are taking over the responsibility of following updates, security vulnerability reports, ..

Comment: I just wonder even though Linux can be such a solid development environment, why is installing a visual diff tool so difficult?  Ubuntu seems the easiest, but Fedora, CentOS, RHEL 5 can be quite a bit harder

Comment: Fedora, CentOS and other community Linux OSs are no different than Ubuntu.. It's difficult in RHEL because enterprise OSs like this presents restricted environment for security and they don't maintain packages for all open source projects.